# Problema subiendo archivo con Django

Tags: python, django

Recién empece a trabajar con Django 1.11. Estoy tratando de subir un archivo mediante un formulario. Les dejo unas muestras de mi código a continuación.

En primer lugar mi formulario en forms.py:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Titulo')
    file = forms.FileField(label='Archivo')
```

La vista en views.py:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/prueba/resultado/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'calendarioTest/formulario.html', {'form': form})

def resultado(request):
    var = 'Muchas gracias'
    return render(request, 'calendarioTest/resultado.html', {'var':var})
```

En las rutas de mi aplicación tengo:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^prueba/', include('calendarioTest.urls')),
]
```

calendarioTest.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^exportar/',views.CalendarioTest, name='exportar'),
    url(r'^formulario/', views.upload_file, name = 'formulario'),
    url(r'^resultado/', views.resultado, name='resultado'),
]
```

Y el template del formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form action="/prueba/formulario/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sin embargo, cuando selecciono el archivo y pongo el titulo en lugar de redireccionarme a la pagina que especifico, me dice que no he seleccionado ningún archivo. Active el debug y cuando llego a la parte de `if form.is_valid()` me dice que el formulario es invalido, y en la pagina de mi navegador puedo ver el titulo escrito pero el campo del archivo me dice que no ha seleccionado ninguno archivo.

Esto me molesta, porque cuando el formulario solamente contaba con campos como titulo, nombre o email, el formulario era valido y me redireccionaba a la pagina especificada.

Pudieran decirme que estoy haciendo mal en este caso? Buscando una solucion me halle esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example pero la respuesta no me sirvio, el formulario sigue siendo invalido y en el navegador sigo viendo el error de que no se ha seleccionado ningun archivo.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando trabajes con archivos en tu formulario tienes que especificar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form action="/prueba/formulario/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Esto está especificado en la documentación de Django para [Basic file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Es decir, `request.FILES` solo contendrá información de tus archivos siempre y cuando hayas usado el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Es por eso que te sale el error.

Comment: Gracias! Ha funcionado! Parece que al leerme la documentacion no preste atencion a esa nota.